# $f(x)=f(y)$ implies that $f(x)=f(ax+(1-a)y)$. Show that $f(x)=f(y)$ implies that $f(x+b)=f(y+b).$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality

$f$ is continuous and weakly increasing (in all variable) $\mathbb R^n$ function.

$n>1$

For any $x,y$, $f(x)=f(y)$ implies that $f(x)=f(ax+(1-a)y)$ for any $a\in(0,1).$

Show that $f(x)=f(y)$ implies that $f(x+b)=f(y+b).$

It seems really obvious...

Comment: What does weakly increasing mean on $\mathbb R^n$? Increasing in each variable?

Comment: @NikhilSahoo Yes!

Comment: As stated, the given result is false. Taken $n=1$; let $f(x)=x$ for $x\geq 0$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Then $f(-1)=f(0),$ but $f(-1+b)\neq f(0+b)$ for any $b\in (0,1)$.

Comment: @NikhilSahoo You are right! I forgot to put $n>1$.

Comment: It's still wrong. This user has always been posting mostly low quality questions, which are sometimes wrong and mostly shows little effort. And even got 2k+ reps from these...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not correct.

Counter Example:

Suppose that $f(x,y) = (0,0)$ for $x<0$, $f(x,y) = (x,0)$ for $x\geq0$.

Then $f$ is a continuous, weakly increasing (for each variable) $\Bbb R^2$ function.

Now take $v = (0,0), u=(-1,0)$, then $f(v)=f(u)=0$,

but for $b=(1,0)$ we have $1 = f(1,0) = f(v+b) \ne f(u+b) = f(0,0) = 0$.

This idea will work for every $n$.